# Better practice for custom rows and cells in a tableview JavaFX

Tags: java, mysql, database, javafx, tableview

I made a table-view that looks like the following:

[image: http://s33.postimg.org/pn9u1al0v/otra_pregunta.png]

For doing this I made the following:

1.- Create and observable list of the POJO that represents the table "Modulo" in MySQL database, with this list I created the columns  of the table-view with this code:

```
public ObservableList<Modulo> cargaTablaHabilitadosMasHoras(Connection conex){
    ObservableList<Modulo> listaMod = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    String sql = "SELECT id_Mod, nombre_Mod, \n" +
                 "  Turno_Mod, capacidad_Mod, id_Us, \n" +
                 "  status_Mod \n"+
                 "FROM Modulo;";
    //Static first column
    listaMod.add(new Modulo("123", "Horario", "Rhut", 10, "123", true));
    try(PreparedStatement stta = conex.prepareStatement(sql);
          ResultSet res = stta.executeQuery()) {
        while (res.next()) {
            if (res.getBoolean("status_Mod")) {
               listaMod.add(new Modulo( res.getString ("id_Mod"), 
                                     res.getString ("nombre_Mod"), 
                                     res.getString ("Turno_Mod"), 
                                     res.getInt    ("capacidad_Mod"), 
                                     res.getString ("id_Us"), 
                                     res.getBoolean("status_Mod"))); 
            }
        }
    }catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listaMod;
}
```

2.- Create a table with the custom data with this code:

```
public void otraTabla(Connection conex){
    //loads the observable list of the POJO that represents the table Modulo
    columns = modu.cargaTablaHabilitadosMasHoras(conex);
    /*
    creates and observable list that is going to be the base 
    of the tableview creating a grid of 8 x number of colums 
    obtained of the first list + 1 column that represents the hours
    */
    ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    row.addAll("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8");
    //for loop that iterates the tableview columns
    for(Modulo columName : columns) {
        //creates and column object to be integrated and manipulated 
        //whit the name of the column in the first list
        TableColumn<String, String> col = new TableColumn(columName.getNombre_Mod());
        //verify if is the first column with contains the hours
        if (columName.getNombre_Mod().equals("Horario")) {
            //if is the one creates the rows with the hours staring at 6 am
            col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
                //star at 6 am
                LocalTime lol = LocalTime.of(6, 0);
                //get the value of ObservableList<String> row for for adding to LocalTime
                Integer p = Integer.valueOf(cellData.getValue());
                //adds the value to localtime
                lol = lol.plusHours(p);
                //Gives a format for the hour
                DateTimeFormatter kk = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm");
                //returns the new String
                return new SimpleStringProperty(lol.format(kk));
            });

        }else{
            //if is a column load dinamically then gets 
            //the next date where there is space in the column at that time 
            col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
                String regresaFecha = "";
                //Conection to the database it conection to the database it 
                //have to be inside of the loop or else the conection is lost
                try(Connection localConnection = dbConn.conectarBD()) {
                    //get the level of the row in this case the hour
                    LocalTime lol = LocalTime.of(6, 0);
                    Integer p = Integer.valueOf(cellData.getValue());
                    lol = lol.plusHours(p);
                    //calls the method that calculed the next date where there is space in the table of the database 
                    LocalDate fechaApunter = rehab.compararDiaADia(localConnection, Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now()),
                            Time.valueOf(lol), columName.getId_Mod(), columName.getCapacidad_Mod(), 30);
                    //date sent to the row of the tableview
                    regresaFecha = fechaApunter.toString();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return new SimpleStringProperty(regresaFecha);
            });
        }

        //change color of the date depending of the 
        //distant relevant to the day is making the query to the database
        if (!columName.getNombre_Mod().equals("Horario")) {
            col.setCellFactory (coli -> {
                TableCell<String, String> cell = new TableCell<String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (item != null) {
                            LocalDate lol = LocalDate.parse(item);
                            Text text = new Text(item);
                            if (lol.isAfter(LocalDate.now())) {
                                if (lol.isAfter(LocalDate.now().plusDays(5))) {
                                    text.setStyle(" -fx-fill: #990000;" + 
                                                  " -fx-text-alignment:center;");
                                }else
                                    text.setStyle(" -fx-fill: #cccc00;" + 
                                              " -fx-text-alignment:center;");
                            }
                            this.setGraphic(text);
                        }
                    }
                };
                return cell;
            });
        }

        //add the column to the tableview
        tvDisponivilidad.getColumns().addAll(col);
    }
    //add the Observable list place holder
    tvDisponivilidad.setItems(row);
}
```

For loading the data I used this method:

```
public LocalDate compararDiaADia(Connection conex, Date fecha, Time hora, 
        String id_Mod, int capacidad, int dias){
    LocalDate contador = fecha.toLocalDate();
    LocalDate disDeHoy = LocalDate.now();
    for (int i = 0; i < dias; i++) {
        contador = fecha.toLocalDate();
        contador = contador.plusDays(i);
        String sttm = "SELECT COUNT(id_Reab) AS Resultado\n" +
                      "FROM Rehabilitacion\n" +
                      "WHERE '"+contador+"' BETWEEN inicio_Reab AND fin_Reab\n" +
                      "AND horario_Reab = '"+hora+"'\n" +
                      "AND id_Modulo = '"+id_Mod+"';";
        try(PreparedStatement stta = conex.prepareStatement(sttm);
           ResultSet res = stta.executeQuery(); ) {
            if (res.next()) {
                if (res.getInt("Resultado") < capacidad || res.getInt("Resultado") == 0) {
                    disDeHoy = contador;
                    break;
                }else
                    disDeHoy = contador;
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return disDeHoy;
}
```

What this method does is that for each column it checks where is the next day where there is less of the capacity of the module (each module has different capacity)  at certain hour and returns that day, in the calling of the method the hour changes to populate all the rows in the table.

There are several problems with my approach, first is the time, it cost to load the table, it takes like one minute to make the query and populate the table this is a combination of factors but the principal factor is that for every day I made a query to the database and example of this:.
Here is my table where I made the queries:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM imssRehab.Rehabilitacion;
+---------+-------------+------------+-----------------+---------+-----------+
| id_Reab | inicio_Reab | fin_Reab   | horario_Reab    | id_Prog | id_Modulo |
+---------+-------------+------------+-----------------+---------+-----------+
| 1       | 2016-06-01  | 2016-06-10 | 07:00:00.000000 | 1       | 215A3     |
| 2       | 2016-06-01  | 2016-06-10 | 07:00:00.000000 | 1       | 215A3     |
| 3       | 2016-06-01  | 2016-06-10 | 07:00:00.000000 | 1       | 215A3     |
| 4       | 2016-06-01  | 2016-06-10 | 07:00:00.000000 | 1       | 215A3     |
| 5       | 2016-06-01  | 2016-06-10 | 07:00:00.000000 | 1       | 215A3     |
| 6       | 2016-06-01  | 2016-06-10 | 07:00:00.000000 | 1       | 215A3     |
+---------+-------------+------------+-----------------+---------+-----------+
```

here is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id_Reab) AS Resultado
FROM Rehabilitacion
WHERE '2016-06-01' BETWEEN inicio_Reab AND fin_Reab
AND horario_Reab = '07:00'
AND id_Modulo = '215A3';
```

The result is 6 in this module my capacity is 5 so I have to advance a day and ask again until it finds a day where are less than 5 in this example until 2016-06-11. To get here I have to make 10 queries and open 10 connections. I use a connection pool and it's very efficient, but it gets overwhelmed by these 10 queries are only for the first row in the first column, normally there are between 15 to 20 columns assuming there is only one query for a row, it still is around 120-160 connections.

I try to reuse a connection every time I can, my first instinct was to use the connection that get pass to the method for loading the Observable List of modules but when I do this the method that makes the query of dates receives the connection closed with out and apparent reason. After many tests I came to the conclusion that has something to do with the lambda of the setCellValueFactory method, and if I want to make a connection it has to be  inside creating more connections. I would like i try to alleviate this by loading the table in a different thread with a Task but the results where similar.

A solution to this  would be to make a POJO especially for table but I don't think it's possible to create a class dynamically. I could have a POJO whit 20 possible columns and only load the columns that I would use, but what happens when there is more than 20 columns or the name of the modules changes?

So my question is this: how do I make the creation of the table more rapidly? And is there a better way to achieve this table? I don't like my solution with code it's more complex than I would like I'm hoping for a better and cleaner way.